# Git - Commit history showing Origin/branchName

Tags: git

Could someone explain why the highlighted commit `dacc225232` has the red text in brackets? It's not the name of the branch that was merged and the original branch was created from main.

Git history:

[image]

Comment: It means there is a branch called `origin/feat(eam)/geocoding` that is pointing to this commit. It's not trying to tell you anything about the original branch, or the name of the branch that existed at the point it was merged. Rather, it's telling you that right now, there is a branch pointing to this commit.

Answer (score 1):

Coloring is arbitrary. In this case, it's the name of a *remote tracking branch* (that is what the `origin/` prefix means) and the coloring rules have been set to display those names in red.

So in effect it's telling you where your local Git believes that branch name is pointing *on the remote machine* (such as GitHub). That information is subject to change (if, for instance, you go a `git fetch` and your local Git discovers there has been a change on the remote server).